# How to split the column "name" into two "first name" and "last name"

Tags: sql, postgresql

The "name" column can have compound names and I want to separate them this way, with a query in PostgreSQL so it should remain:

It should remain:

[image]

I try this query but don't separate when the name has 'mrs' or 'ms'

```
SELECT substring(name from 1 for (POSITION(' ' IN name))) "first_name" 
      ,substring(name from (POSITION(' ' IN name))+1) "last_name"
FROM flores_comahue fc
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep `Mr` but not `Mrs`?

Comment: i want to keep the 2 of us.

Comment: Provide data as *text*, please, not as image. And clarify the criteria for your split.

Comment: Its seems like the split must be done on last space, but the last row of your vague sample data doesn't follow this. Is that sample row incorrect? If not, tell us how to split, please.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Good luck with composite first/last names... how would you (automatically) split `Millie Bobby Brown`?

Answer (score 0):

I would first clean up the things you don't want to keep (like `MRS.` or `MD`), then split the resulting string:

```
select elements[1] as first_name, 
       elements[2] as last_name
from (       
  select regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(name, '\s*(MRS.|MR.|MD)\s*', '', 'g'), '\s+') as elements
  from flores_comahue
) t
```

The `regexp_replace()` can be extended to remove more titles or "noise".

I used `regexp_split_to_array()` rather than `string_to_array()` to deal with values that use more than one space to separate the words.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/T_5-To0n)